# How to change a given date in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" format to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z" format in groovy

Tags: groovy, ready-api

How to convert a given date in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` format to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` format in groovy 
For example, the given date is `2019-03-18 16:20:05.6401383`. I want it to converted to `2019-03-18T16:20:05.6401383Z`

This is the code Used:

```
 def date = format1.parse("2019-03-18 16:20:05.6401383");
 String settledAt = format2.format(date)
 log.info ">>> "+*date*+"   "+*settledAt*
```

The result, where the date is getting changed somehow: `Mon Mar 18 18:06:46 EDT 2019` & `2019-03-18T18:06:46.383Z`

Thanks in advance for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Java 8+ and Groovy 2.5+, I would use the new Date/Time API:

```
import java.time.*

def date = LocalDateTime.parse('2019-03-18 16:20:05.6401383', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnn')
String settledAt = date.format(/yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnn'Z'/)
```

This is presuming the input date has a "Zulu" time zone.

Comment: Thanks, bdkosher, but did not work as is. However, I figured the way to make it work, based on  LocalDateTime.parse.

Comment: @user10829672 If you have a working solution for your problem, it's OK to add your own answer (and even vote it).  It will help others that find the question.

Answer (score 0):

it's a feature of java

```
def date = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS","2019-03-18 16:20:05.6401383")
```

returns

```
Mon Mar 18 18:06:46 EET 2019
```

the problem that java handles only milliseconds `SSS` (3 digits after seconds)

but you are providing 7 digits for milliseconds `6401383`

as workaround remove extra digits with regexp:

```
def sdate1 = "2019-03-18 16:20:05.6401383"
sdate1 = sdate1.replaceAll( /\d{3}(\d*)$/, '$1') //keep only 3 digits at the end
def date = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",sdate1)
def sdate2 = date.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
```